# Customize plugin update "new version is available" text

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, updates

I'm looking to customize the "There is a new version of XYZ available." text on the Plugins list page. I know the code is in [wp-admin/includes/update.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/56c162fbc9867f923862f64f1b4570d885f1ff03/wp-admin/includes/update.php#L592), however I'm not certain how to call this out or pull it out in a filter/callback. Basically, I want to be able to customize this message in a plugin. Thanks for any help or direction!

Comment: Try [`gettext`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext)

Comment: @rudtek Been playing with pre_site_transient_update_plugins per https://jasonjalbuena.com/disable-wordpress-update-notifications/ but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the text is processed by `_()` function, then, of course, you can modify it using [`gettext`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter.

```
function change_update_notification_msg( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) 
{

    if ( is_admin() ) {
        $texts = array(
            'There is a new version of %1$s available. <a href="%2$s" %3$s>View version %4$s details</a>.' => 'My custom notification. There is a new version of %1$s available. <a href="%2$s" %3$s>View version %4$s details</a>.',
            'There is a new version of %1$s available. <a href="%2$s" %3$s>View version %4$s details</a>. <em>Automatic update is unavailable for this theme.</em>' => 'My custom notification. There is a new version of %1$s available. <a href="%2$s" %3$s>View version %4$s details</a>. <em>Automatic update is unavailable for this theme.</em>',
            'There is a new version of %1$s available. <a href="%2$s" %3$s>View version %4$s details</a> or <a href="%5$s" %6$s>update now</a>.' => 'My custom notification. There is a new version of %1$s available. <a href="%2$s" %3$s>View version %4$s details</a> or <a href="%5$s" %6$s>update now</a>.'
        );

        if ( array_key_exists( $untranslated_text, $texts ) ) {
            return $texts[$untranslated_text];
        }
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_update_notification_msg', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This text can't be filtered afaik.
You can append text though: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/in_plugin_update_message-file/